# User Invitations based on invite links

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

my scenario is i have a teams model, team leads send out invite links to the team,
url schema "domain/{team.id}/{team.name}/"
i'm using dj_rest_auth for authentication,
these invite links are sent to un-registered users.
whne user clicks on url they are redirected to the signup view.
now i need to add a user to the team(team id received in url) after they signup,
i can't figure out how to pass the team id to user_sign_up post_save signal in allauth, django Sessionstore doesn't work as the key generated is different each time [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views), i'm new to django rest framework. i also looked at [django globals](https://pypi.org/project/django-globals/), but that didn't help either.
any help would be much much appreciated,

app.views:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
def inviteduser(request, pk, name):
    s = SessionStore()
    s['team-id'] = pk
    s.create()
    print(s.session_key)
    return redirect('http://localhost:8000/account/registration')
```

accounts.signals:

```
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from django.dispatch import receiver
from core.models import TeamMembers
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore


@receiver(user_signed_up)
def user_signed_up(request, user, **kwargs):
    s = SessionStore(session_key='gm0p279oeqvu385fy28btbyjzhak8a2j')
    # if request.session['team-id']:
    teamid = s['team-id']
    # print(teamid)
    teammember = TeamMembers(member_id=user.id, team_id=teamid)
    teammember.save()
```

i have a custom user model and a corresponding custom serializer.

account.models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

accounts.serializer:

```
from django.db import transaction
from rest_framework import serializers
from dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer

from accounts.models import User


class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(allow_blank=False, required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=False, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=False, required=True)

    # Define transaction.atomic to rollback the save operation in case of error
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user.email = self.data.get('email')
        user.first_name = self.data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.data.get('last_name')
        user.save()
        print(request.session.get('team-id'))
        return user
```

Comment: Couldn't you pass team id in query_params in redirect and then in registration view get them from request?

Comment: That would solve my problem, but i can't override the registration view.